# Como alterar o tempo de duração de um javafx Tooltip

Tags: java, javafx

Ao executar um `javafx.scene.control.Tooltip` do JavaFX, o texto fica aparecendo por um período de tempo e desaparece.

Como configurar o tempo de duração do texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir do Java 9, é possível fazer isto através do método `setShowDuration`

Exemplo:

```
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("Exemplo Tooltip");
tooltip.setShowDuration(Duration.seconds(5));
```

Também é possível configurar o delay para aparecer na tela com o método `setShowDelay` e o tempo que o texto fixa aparecendo após o mouse sair da área que está sendo utilizado com o método `setHideDelay`.